# Required slot prompts even if the value is mentioned in the utterence

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am developing an Alexa skill with a required slot `"name"` for which I have added a prompt of **"What is your name"**.

The utterances for the intent are:

*1. note my name

 2. note my name as {name}*

For both the utterances, I get the prompt what is your name.

Comment: Did you try adding some random names to your slot? If you provide some random names, it'll come to know what type of utterances the user will speak.

Comment: Yes I did try that.. If I say "note my name" or "note my name as Joe", in both the cases it says the prompt  that I have set i.e. "What is your name"

Comment: utterances for the intent are: 1) note my name 2) note my name as {name}

 Thats why you are getting this. make a slot of name and mark that slot as needed and in question write what is your name ? and in sample utterance write note my name as {name} and in intent utterance write only note my name you have to use dialogue directivce .

Comment: It'll be very helpful for us, if you could just provide the schema of your skill. It is there in build section > JSON Editor. (You could upload it somewhere, maybe github and put a link of your schema here.)

Comment: @HarshButani Did you mean utterances for the "slot" are 1. note my name 2. note my name as {name}? If not then that is incorrect. You cannot have that utterance for the intent it should be for the slot "name".

Comment: @Amey do you mean to say that a user can never invoke an intent by the following utterences 1) note my name 2) note my name as joe for the same intent? I tries making the change you suggested but in that case it works for only the "note my name" utterence and for the "note my name as Joe" it goes to the Fall Back Intent

Comment: @NikhilWagh please fing the original schema : https://gist.github.com/Harshhb101/1a093c4ff7c9ed52975b587a60e8cd12


and Amey's suggestions: https://gist.github.com/Harshhb101/e1f8d27ce9e6e503c826d06ce92dedcc

Comment: @HarshButani the second seems to be correct. 
Just a suggestion though, when the user speaks "Note my name", don't make Alexa say "What is your name?". That doesn't seem good. Instead you could make it say "I'm listening" or "please go ahead".

Comment: @HarshButani you need to give more sample utterances for your intent, only one is not going to help you. You should write as many as you can.

Answer (score 1):

**Utterances for your intent should be something like these :**

1. note my name
2. My name is {name}
3. note my name as {name}

**Prompts for your slot "name"**

1. Please tell me your name
2. What is your name?
3. Do you even have a name?

**Utterances for your slot "name"**

1. {name}
2. My name is {name}
3. It is {name}

Even though you are using `AMAZON.US_FIRST_NAME`, it would be wise to provide some *slot values* for the slot "name".
For example:

**Slot value samples for the slot "name"**

1. joe
2. sam
3. Martha
4. Gopal

If still `AMAZON.FallBackIntent` is called, then please show me your complete code.

Comment: Did this solved your problem, or is there anything else you're trying to figure out? Consider accepting the solution if it did solved your error.